# Solving differential equation...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is this differential equation that I could not solve. Can someone please help me solve it?

$$y'=-\frac{4t}{y}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh hell. I have been thinking about it for half an hour and it didn't stuck me. Im having a bad day. thanks @Fundamental

Comment: Have you looked at examples in your notes or in your textbook?

Comment: It's a separable equation. Try replacing $y'=\frac{dy}{dt}$ and gathering $y$'s and $t$'s on their own sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If y=y(t)...

[\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} =  - \frac{{4t}}{y}\\
ydy =  - 4tdt\\
\int {ydy =  - 4\int {tdt} } \\
\frac{{{y^2}}}{2} =  - 2{t^2} + c\\
y = \sqrt { - 4{t^2} + c} 
\end{array}]

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-4t}{y}$

$y dy=-4t dt$

Integrate both sides.

$\frac{y^2}{2} = -2t^2+c$

$y^2=-4t^2+c$